# Mistakes in my ingress yaml file or process?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying kubernetes and making some progress, but I'm running into an issue with ingress when trying to make my hello world app publicly available.

**SUCCESS WITH DEPLOYMENT AND SERVICE**

I created a simple `hello world` type of nodejs app and pushed the image to my docker hub `johnlai2004/swarm2`.  I successfully created a deployment and service with this yaml file:

`nodejs.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nodejs-hello
  labels:
    app: nodejs-hello
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs-hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodejs-hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodejs-hello
        image: johnlai2004/swarm2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodejs-hello-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nodejs-hello
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30000
```

I uploaded these files to a VPS with a new installation of ubuntu 20.04, minikube, kubectl and docker.

I ran the following commands and got the results I wanted:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
kubectl apply -f nodejs.yaml
minikube service nodejs-hello-service
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |         NAME         | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | nodejs-hello-service |        3000 | http://192.168.49.2:30000 |
|-----------|----------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
```

When I do a `wget http://192.168.49.2:30000`, I get an `index.html` file that says `hello from nodejs-hello-556dc868-6lrdz at 12/19/2021, 10:29:56 PM`.  This is perfect.

**FAILURE WITH INGRESS**

Next, I want to use ingress so that I can see the page at `http://website.example.com`  (replace `website.example.com` with the actual domain that points to my server). I put this file on my server:

`nodejs-ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nodejs-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: website.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: nodejs-hello-service
              port:
                number: 3000
```

And I ran the commands

```
minikube addons enable ingress
kubectl apply -f nodejs-ingress.yaml
kubectl get ingress
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS                   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
nodejs-ingress   <none>   website.example.com     localhost   80      15m
```

But when I visit `http://website.example.com` with my browser, the browser says it can't connect.  Using `wget http://website.example.com` gave the same connection issue.

Can someone point out what I may have done wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

I ran these commands because I think it shows I didn't install ingress-controller in the right name space?

```
kubectl get pod -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create--1-tqsrp     0/1     Completed   0          4h25m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch--1-sth26      0/1     Completed   0          4h25m
ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-tmx72   1/1     Running     0          4h25m

kubectl get pod -n default
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nodejs-hello-556dc868-6lrdz   1/1     Running   0          40m
```

So does this mean my nodejs app is in a name space that doesn't have access to the ingress controller?

---

UPDATE 2

I also tried following [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) step by step.
One difference I noticed was when I ran the command `kubectl get ingress`, `ADDRESS` says `localhost`.   But in the guide, it says it is supposed to be `172.17.0.15`

[image]

Does this difference matter?  I'm hosting things in a cloud vps called linode.com.   Does that change the way I do things?

Comment: Did you deploy an ingress controller as well? And expose it on the hosts via a `hostPort` or other mechanism?

Comment: @vaizki, i just updated my question with notes. I think it means my ingress controller is in the wrong name space?

Comment: The ingress controller can be in a separate namespace, that is not the issue. If the controller is set up right, accessing the URL should at least give you a 404. If you get connection refused or timeout the controller is not reachable via the host/port your URL is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you have is expected. Let me explain why. Going point through point, and at the end I will present my tips.

First I think it's worth to present minikube architecture. I'm assuming you have installed minikube using default driver `docker` as you have address `192.168.49.2` which is standard for [`docker` driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/).

The layers are:

- your VM with Ubuntu 20.04
- Kubernetes cluster setup by minikube which is docker container with address `192.168.49.2` on the VM

So... you can not just run `curl` on the VM using a `localhost` address to connect to the service. [The `localhost` is referring to the device that you are making curl request (so your VM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), not the docker container. That's why you need to use the `192.168.49.2` address.

You can type `docker ps -a`, and you will see the container which is an actual Kubernetes cluster. You can exec into it using `docker exec` command and then run `curl` command with the localhost address:

```
user@example-ubuntu-minikube-template-1:~$ curl -H "Host: hello-world.info" localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
user@example-ubuntu-minikube-template-1:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
1a4ba3895990   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   4 days ago   Up 4 days   127.0.0.1:49157->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49156->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49155->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49154->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:49153->32443/tcp   minikube
user@example-ubuntu-minikube-template-1:~$ docker exec -it 1a sh
# curl -H "Host: hello-world.info" localhost
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-79d88c97d6-nl4c7
```

Keep in mind that you can access this container only from the VM that is hosting this container. Without any further configuration it's you can't just access it from the other VMs. It is possible, but not recommended.

Good explanation in the [minikube FAQ](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/faq/):

> How can I access a minikube cluster from a remote network?

> minikube’s primary goal is to quickly set up local Kubernetes clusters, and therefore we strongly discourage using minikube in production or for listening to remote traffic. By design, minikube is meant to only listen on the local network.

> However, it is possible to configure minikube to listen on a remote network. This will open your network to the outside world and is not recommended. If you are not fully aware of the security implications, please avoid using this.

> For the docker and podman driver, use  `--listen-address`  flag:
>
> ```
> minikube start --listen-address=0.0.0.0
> ```

So I'd avoid it. I will present a better possible solution at the end of the answer.

You asked:

> But when I visit  `http://website.example.com`  with my browser, the browser says it can't connect. Using  `wget http://website.example.com`  gave the same connection issue.

> Can someone point out what I may have done wrong?

Your computer does not know what it is `website.example.com`. It's not aware that this name is used by your Ingress. If your computer does not find this name in [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) it will start looking for this over the Internet.

So you have some possible solutions:

- use `curl -H 'HOST: website.example.com' http://192.168.49.2:80` - it will work only on the VM where is minikube
- [add host to the hosts file](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) - something like `192.168.49.2 website.example.com` - it will work only on the VM where is minikube
- Setup a bare-metal cluster (more details in the sum up section) and point the domain address to the VM address.  In GCP and AWS you can do it using  [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns) or [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/). On linode cloud maybe [this one - DNS Manager](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/dns-manager/) ?

**EDIT:**
You wrote that you have a domain pointed to the server, so please just check the sum up section of my answer.

Also you asked:

> I ran these commands because I think it shows I didn't install ingress-controller in the right name space?

> So does this mean my nodejs app is in a name space that doesn't have access to the ingress controller?

[It's absolutely normal](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start):

> It will install the controller in the `ingress-nginx` namespace, creating that namespace if it doesn't already exist.

Also:

> I also tried following this guide step by step:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

> One difference I noticed was when I ran the command  `kubectl get ingress`,  `ADDRESS`  says  `localhost`. But in the guide, it says it is supposed to be  `172.17.0.15`

> Does this difference matter? I'm hosting things in a cloud vps called linode.com. Does that change the way I do things?

It's also normal and expected when using minikube with a docker driver.

To sum up / other tips:

- Minkube is fine for local testing; you can easily access apps and services using from the host - check [Accessing apps](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/).
- However, for exposing it outside the network you should consider using solutions like [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) or [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray) for cluster setup + [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) for LoadBalancer solution. Check "[Bare-metal considerations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)" and [Exposing a Kubernetes service on a bare-metal cluster over the external network architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583350/exposing-a-kubernetes-service-on-a-bare-metal-cluster-over-the-external-network)
- If you are planning to use your service with ingress, don't use LoadBalancer type. It's ok to use ClusterIP.

Comment: Thanks, I decided I should jsut set up real bare metal machines and set up a cluster with multiple nodes to test this!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `kubectl get ingress nodejs-ingress` to see if the ingress resource is created successfully.

Then curl with `curl -H 'HOST: <replace with HOSTS from the output of get ingress command>' http://<ADDRESS from the output of get ingress command>:<PORTS from the output of get ingress command>`

Comment: I got this result `curl -H 'HOST: website.example.com' http://localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: I updated my with `UPDATE 2` that shows another guide i'm following.  The guide says the `ADDRESS` is supposed to be of hte format `(\d+\.){4}`, but my `ADDRESS` is the word `localhost`.

Comment: If you are connecting from your local machine to a VM hosted on linode, the ADDRESS should be the public IP of the VM. Also, there shouldn't be any firewall blocking the port. Otherwise you need to execute the curl **on the VM itself**.

Comment: There is currently no firewall.  Ok, so i have to figure out why kubernetes, or minikube, or ingress, or some dhcp server, or whatever is responsible for issuing ip address...isn't actually issuing an ip address

Comment: In the case of minikube, that ADDRESS is normally the host IP - which in this case your VM on linode.

Comment: i also ran the curl statement from the actual VM.  Basically I `ssh root@website.example.com`, then I ran the `curl -H 'HOST: website.example.com' http://localhost:80`, which gave conneciton refused error mentioned earlier

Comment: Ok i'll try to figure out why `minikube` can't seem to find the host machine's ip address.  TYping `minikube ip` gives `192.168.49.2`, which is also not the host machine's external ip address. So I have to figure how to configure minikube

Comment: Do you get result by: `curl -H 'HOST: website.example.com' http://192.168.49.2:80`?

Comment: Yes, this command produced the hello world message `ssh root@website.example.com "curl -H 'HOST: website.example.com' http://192.168.49.2:80"`.  But if I do `curl http://website.example.com` from any other mcachine, i get the connection refused

Comment: I replaced website.example.com with my actual domain name (didn't want to give away the client branded domain name in my examples)

Comment: Ok, your ingress-nginx and your sample web pod is functioning now. Note "website.example.com" is not a registered domain name so you should expect connection refused when you connect **from outside** the VM. If you use a registered name, make your domain name A record is pointed to the your VM public IP. For minikube to listen on this IP, you can try `minikube start --listen-address <public IP>`